# Can I assign same value to multiple variables in C?

Tags: c

I tried like

```
int a=b=3;
```

but the compiler says `'b' undeclared`.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I bet the compiler is right and `b` is not declared. So then declare it. Also, in this case, it's only `b` that is being assigned to – the variable `a` is **not** assigned, it's initialized.

Comment: `int a, b, c; a = b = c = 3;`

Comment: If it says it's undeclared, then declare it.

Comment: I see it works when I declare the variables first and then assign the value, thanks HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `,` to declare the variables in a single line first

```
int a, b, c, ... , last;
```

and then you can assign to them all at once

```
a = b = c = ... = last = 3;
```

note that

```
int a = b = 3;
```

which is equivalent to

```
int a = (b = 3);
```

will declare `a` and initialize it with the result `b = 3`, which in turn will assign `3` to `b`, which is **UNDECLARED**

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this because the compiler interprets that the value `3` to `b`should be assigned and `b` is undeclared

You can do

```
int b;

int a=b=3;
```